# Can 大変mean amazing and awful?

Tags: word-choice

I have heard the word spoken on occasion, but I am not sure if it can be used in both situations. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can mean both awful and very very

これは大変だ。(This is terrible)

大変[助]{たす}かりました。(You helped me very much!)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to paullb's answer, if you don't use 大変 as an adverb or adjective  modifying another word, it usually means awful or terrible.